# Invalid Json while using get requests Flask

Tags: json, flask, python-requests

I need to request a PG Database thru an API, I am using Flask `requests` package :

```
 payload = {'key':'**', 'schema':'**', 'table':'testh','where_clause':'0', 'liste_fields':'*'}
r = requests.get('https://myapi/', params=payload, verify=False)
```

I need to get all the content of my `testh` table store in a JSON, but the function `r.json()` gets me this invalid JSON :

```
{'id': {'0': '1', '1': '2', '2': '3', '3': '4'}, 'brand': {'0': 'apple', '1': 'microsoft', '2': 'google', '3': 'amazon'}}
```

I need a JSON as : {0: {id:'2', brand:'apple}, 1:{id:'2', brand:'microsoft}, ....}

[image: Here is my table in Postgresql]

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': {'0': '1', '1': '2', '2': '3', '3': '4'}, 'brand': {'0': 'apple', '1': 'microsoft', '2': 'google', '3': 'amazon'}}
d = pd.DataFrame(d).to_dict(orient='index')
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'id': '1', 'brand': 'apple'},
 '1': {'id': '2', 'brand': 'microsoft'},
 '2': {'id': '3', 'brand': 'google'},
 '3': {'id': '4', 'brand': 'amazon'}}
```

It is just a guess, but maybe the API used pandas as well and if you call to_dict() without parameter you get exactly the output you are describing.